# JQuery. Set input placeholder to last value typed into input after 1 second has passed. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I need to **Set the input placeholder to last value typed into input after 1 second has passed**. The reason is that if the user once again deletes everything from it, the placeholder will now show the last value typed into input after last autoupdate AJAX call **AND NOT the placeholder value loaded during original page load**.

**WORKING CODE**

```
  function autoSave(client_id, project_id, mainsheet_id, t_id, t_val) {

    if (t_val != '') {

      // Refresh variables just in case.
      client_id = $('#CLIENT_ID').val();
        project_id = $('#PROJECT_ID').val();
        mainsheet_id = $('#MAINSHEET_ID').val();

            // AJAX POST request to run MySQL UPDATE query on this database field ( WTRESRVD ).
            $.ajax({
                url: "processor.php",
                method: "GET",
                data: {
                    postCLIENT_ID: client_id,
                    postPROJECT_ID: project_id,
                    postMAINSHEET_ID: mainsheet_id,
                    postT_ID: t_id,
                    postT_VAL: t_val
                },
                dataType: "text",
                beforeSend: function() {
                    // setting a timeout
                    $('#status').text('Please wait...');

                },

                success: function(data) {
                    // If data return after a successful request isn't an empty string..
                  // ADD SERVER RESPONSE HANDING HERE.

                  /* Status Codes

                  return 0 = Nothing to Update
                  return 1 = Successful Update Query
                  return 2 = Database Connection refused
                  return 3 = MySQL Query Error OR Wrong URL Parameters */

                  // If data return 0 = Nothing to Update
                  if (data == '0') {

                  $('#status').text("Status: Nothing changed. Nothing saved.").show();
                  // ..fadeOut over 3 seconds. 
                  $('#status').fadeOut(5000);

                  }

                  // If data return 1 = Successful Update Query
                  if (data == '1') {

                  // Create variable time to reference later.
                  var time = showTime();
                  // Update div status with last saved time stamp then..
                  $('#status').text("Status: Saved @ " + time).show();
                  // ..fadeOut over 3 seconds. 
                  $('#status').fadeOut(5000);

                  }

                  // return 2 = Database Connection refused
                  if (data == '2') {

                  $('#status').text("Status: Database Connection refused.").show();
                  // ..fadeOut over 3 seconds. 
                  $('#status').fadeOut(5000);

                  }

                  // return 3 = MySQL Query Error OR Wrong URL Parameters
                  if (data == '3') {

                  $('#status').text("Status: MySQL Query Error OR Wrong URL Parameters.").show();
                  // ..fadeOut over 3 seconds. 
                  $('#status').fadeOut(5000);

                  }

                }

            });
        } else {

        // like this maybe???
        // not working...
        $(t_val).attr("placeholder", t_val);

        }

  }
```

Comment: What is your value `t_val`? Does it correspond to the element, or to its value? If it's the element, it's likely that you're missing a hashtag in your jQuery selector `$(t_val).attr("placeholder", t_val);`. Also, you're probably looking for `t_val.val()` in the `attr()`. You're looking for something like `$(#field).attr("placeholder", "string");`.

Comment: So.. This looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.queue()` and `.delay()` to perform a task in N seconds

```
$("#selector").delay(1000, "placeholder").queue("placeholder", function() {
  $(this).prop("placeholder", "value" /* set placeholder value here */);
}).dequeue("placeholder");
```

Comment: I don't really understand this code. Can you incorporate it into mine?

Comment: @Vini Not sure what you mean. You are using the code at `else` statement, yes?

Comment: The code at else is just an approximation. Precisely what I am looking for as an example.

Comment: `.queue()` queues a function to be called when `.dequeue()` is called, or when the function that is passed as parameter to `.queue()` `next` parameter which is a function is called. When the queue has a `queueName`, at Answer `"placeholder"`, it is possible to delay the call to `.dequeue()` by using the same `queueName` at second parameter to `.delay()` call, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022701/change-easing-functions-on-animations-in-jquery-queue/